# Nuxtjs cannot fetch $content with .where() using $route.params

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm new to Nuxt, but not new to vue.
i am using Nuxt as an spa (not SSR)

I'm using the `@nuxt/content` module to get json data stored in files and display.

I am trying to display a single item on a detail page using something like this

```js
const id = this.$route.params.id; // is 1

console.log(id); // correctly console logs 1

const work = await this.$content("works")
  .where({ id: id })
  .fetch();

console.log(work);
```

This doesn't work and it console logs an empty array.
The strange thing is if i substitute that id for a number directly `.where({ id: 1 })` it works and rightly returns an array of one object.

i feel like i'm missing something. any help?

Btw i'm running the function in a mounted() hook.

folder structure for content

[image: content file structure]

PS:
i know there are other ways to accomplish what i want, for instance this works:

```
const id = this.$route.params.id;
const work = await this.$content("works/work-" + id).fetch();
```

But not only does this rely on the file name structure, i'd really like to know what i am doing wrong or if the initial approach is possible.

Comment: Hmm did you check if its number `console.log(typeof id)`

Comment: @ifaruki you're correct. that was the issue. i had to transform the id from string to integer for it to work